# I had defined a javascript global variable in a tag file, I want to read that variable in tabs of the Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-tag-manager

In my .tag file, I had defined a globalLanguage variable, as for example,

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
       globalLanguage = "${sessionScope.language.isocode}"
</script>
```

In Google Tag Manager, I want to read the value of this globalLanguage, like,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var certona = {
"language" : globalLanguage (?doubt)
}; </script>
```

Please help me in reading the globalLanguage variable defined in the tag file to the Google Tag Manager?

Any help with respect to Google Tag Manager, will be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use LocalStorage for save and get that value in any where.

```
localStorage.setItem('globalLanguage ', YOUR VALUE SAVE HERE); 
and get using
var ans = localStorage.getItem('globalLanguage ');
alert(ans);
```

Comment: Yes using this after setItem item you can get that value in any where.